# How to resolve [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted error in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In the command line, run the TestRunner.js file successfully, got the below error. Don't know how to resolve it. Any suggestion?

[OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop\shirtee_Admin\cypress\videos\TestRunner.js.mp4'

] {
cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop\shirtee_Admin\cypress\videos\TestRunner.js.mp4'

] {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'unlink',
path: 'C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop\shirtee_Admin\cypress\videos\TestRunner.js.mp4'
},
isOperational: true,
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'unlink',
path: 'C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop\shirtee_Admin\cypress\videos\TestRunner.js.mp4'
}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop\shirtee_Admin\cypress\videos\TestRunner.js.mp4'

Comment: What is your npm version ?

Comment: npm version - 7.19.0

Comment: Which version of Cypress are you using? It seems this issue was fixed after version `6.3.0`. Source: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14644